# Incircle in triangle

Tags: geometry

I would like to calculate the incircle radius in a triangle
with 2 internal point with the following distances from
The triangle sides,

```
6,7,12
10,9,4
```

I will appreciate any help or hint
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem!

You asked for hints, so here's how I'd try to do it.

You can find the incircle radius if you know how long all three sides are.

You can describe the sides of a triangle with three equations:

$$y = 0; y = m_1 x; y = m_2 (x-a)$$

This is a triangle with one vertex at the origin, another at $(x,y) = (a, 0)$, and a third somewhere else.  The slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$ have restrictions on them.  Not all combinations of $m_1$ and $m_2$ will make a triangle.

From there, you have two points, and you know the distances from each of these three lines.

Then, use the distance formula to determine $a$ and the two slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$.  This will let you calculate the lengths of the sides, and from there you can get the incircle radius.

Comment: Thanks John, nice solution